# Problems installing gx_freeze

Tags: python, ubuntu, cx-freeze

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Python 2.7.6, and I want to install cx_Freeze. I used the command:

```
pip install cx_Freeze
```

and I got the error:

```
fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

so I did:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

but now I'm getting:

```
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools,  tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_emanuele/cx-Freeze/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Hd6_EY-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_emanuele/cx-Freeze
Storing debug log for failure in /home/emanuele/.pip/pip.log
```

what does it mean this error and how can I fix it?